# "Quota" - "how much" or "how many"?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

If something is countable (e.g. disk space) but is limited by some quota. What you will ask: "how much" or "how many" quota do I have?"

Comment: Neither. You would need "How big/large a quota…" or just "What quota (do I have)?"

Comment: Disk space, surely, is measurable rather than countable; you cannopt have 10,000 of it but may have 100Mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can count something, use **many**:

> How many people were at the party?

When you can't count something, use **much**:

> There was too much paint on the walls.

A quota is a limit; **it is not countable**. What it limits might or might not be countable. So with quota, you should use **much**:

> How much is my quota?

However, it's also very common to say:

> What is my quota?

Answer (score 1):

> much | məCH |
>   determiner & pronoun (more, most) [often with negative or in questions]
>   a large **amount**: [as determiner] : I did not get much sleep | I did so much shopping | [as pronoun] : he does not eat much | they must bear much of the blame.
>
> many | ˈmenē |
>   determiner, pronoun, & adjective (more, most)
>   a large **number** of: [as determiner] : many people agreed with her | [as pronoun] : the solution to many of our problems | many think it is a new craze.

From Apple Dictionary

---

It's clear to see that "much" refers to "amount", yet "many" refers to "number" specifically.

Comment: Hello, Will. It's not that simple. 'Staff' is usually used in a non-count sense, but 'How many staff ...?' shows notional agreement, a shorthand for 'How many members of [your] staff ...?'